# onclick='document.location' get to work in php

Tags: php, html, onclick, href

Simple question; how do I get this to work in php because of the quotes?

```
echo "<table class='tablestyleorchideeaanbod' onClick='document.location = 'links.html''>";
```

Answer (score 1):

By escaping the single quotes.

```
echo "<table class='tablestyleorchideeaanbod' onClick='document.location = \'links.html\''>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but so far it's not working! Bit sad the topic gots this mark without even answered... @rizier123